# IntelliJ / IDEA Gradle plugin not finding source JARs

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, ide

I've been building my Java projects with Gradle, and publishing the with the following setup:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


java {
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        libs(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username depotUsername
                password depotPassword
            }
            url "${depotUrl}/repository/internal/"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the `publishAllPublicationsToMavenRepository`, things work as expected: I can see the results on my server (using our serdes library as an example):

```
.
├── 0.0.1
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.jar
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.jar.md5
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.jar.sha1
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.jar.sha256
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.jar.sha512
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.module
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.module.md5
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.module.sha1
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.module.sha256
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.module.sha512
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.pom
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.pom.md5
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.pom.sha1
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.pom.sha256
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1.pom.sha512
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1-sources.jar
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1-sources.jar.md5
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1-sources.jar.sha1
│   ├── serdes-0.0.1-sources.jar.sha256
│   └── serdes-0.0.1-sources.jar.sha512
├── maven-metadata.xml
├── maven-metadata.xml.md5
├── maven-metadata.xml.sha1
├── maven-metadata.xml.sha256
└── maven-metadata.xml.sha512
```

However, when I try to resolve this in another project, I run the `idea` plugin, and I don't get the sources JAR. I can search for a class name in IntelliJ, and I only get the option to view the decompiled code. If I look in the `.iml` file, I also see that there is no source jar:

```
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar:///Users/tom/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.majeure/serdes/0.0.1/fb710e84a3a74e2548423d258f9ae13da5c35cf8/serdes-0.0.1.jar!/"/>
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC/>
        <SOURCES/>
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
```

This appears to work for dependencies I pull down from MavenCentral, and I can view the source files from those in IntelliJ just fine:

```
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar:///Users/tom/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/28.2-jre/8ec9ed76528425762174f0011ce8f74ad845b756/guava-28.2-jre.jar!/"/>
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC/>
        <SOURCES>
          <root url="jar:///Users/tom/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/28.2-jre/79474f7d08b9a8d03f827161825711d9d62ef09a/guava-28.2-jre-sources.jar!/"/>
        </SOURCES>
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
```

What am I missing here? Have already tried blowing away my Gradle cache, and have deleted my local Maven repo to make sure I'm not getting anything from there.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Versions:

- Gradle 6.0

Comment: Can you share information about the way you consume that published library in the other project?

Comment: Why do you need to use Gradle `idea` plugin specifically? IDE will download sources on re-import from Gradle in Gradle tool window. Does it work?